# "Autoclassification" using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am a newbie at coding and i am stuck with this problem statement as shown below.

- Data:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPmdP.png)
  [Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wMmd.png)
  [Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTj37.png)

Thanks all!!

I managed to get until [enter imaghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/XDwB2.png description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDwB2.png)
but i am stuck to get to ouput1 and 2

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NickODell Hi Nick!! Context is that I am trying to find a way to autoclassify the data, by generate into a report such that it can calculate the ratio/weightage of the occurence of the values in the column as seen from the image in output2. By identifying the ratio, i can compare it against an auditor's threshold to find out whether the discrepancies are immaterial or not.